# Four posts per row

Tags: php, posts

I want to show as

```
 <div class="team-list-wrapper clearfix wow fadeInUp"  data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
<ul id="co-team">
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
</ul>
<ul id="co-team">
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And below is the code I am using:

```
<div class="team-list-wrapper clearfix wow fadeInUp"  data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
<?php $args=array( 'post_type'=>'our-team', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'caller_get_posts'=> 1 ); $my_query = null; $my_query = new WP_Query($args); if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { echo ''; $i = 0; while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); if($i % 4 == 0) { ?>
<ul id="co-team">
    <?php } ?>
    <li class="nav team-list">
        <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id());?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title();?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title();?>">
        <div class="hover-item">
            <div class="actv-desc">
                <div class="team-details">
                    <div class="name">
                        <?php echo get_the_title();?><span><?php the_field('designation'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'content'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php if($i % 4==0 ) { ?>
</ul>
<?php } $i++; endwhile; } wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

And my output is:

```
<ul id="co-team">
<li class="nav team-list">
</ul>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li class="nav team-list">
<li class="nav team-list">
<ul id="co-team">
<li class="nav team-list">
</ul>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li class="nav team-list">
<li class="nav team-list">
<ul id="co-team">
<li class="nav team-list">
</ul>
<li class="nav team-list">
<li class="nav team-list">
<li class="nav team-list">
<ul id="co-team">
<li class="nav team-list">
</ul>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes in your code

1. Use `$i = 1` instead of `$i = 0` (before begining of while loop)
2. You have 2 `IF` condition in which you using % symbol. You need to make changes in first if condition (only in opening ul tag).

Just replace

```
if($i % 4 == 0) {
```

with this

```
 if($i % 4 == 1) {
```

**NOTE**: Don't make this change in your second `IF` condition (codition with closing UL tag i.e. ).

To check what's the difference between previous output and this one, just print value of variable i ($i) near title of post and your will notice why this changes required and how it actually solved the problem.